# How to put a while-loop construction into a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a `command1` doing something useful, for example:

```
command1="ls /home/yevhenii"
```

And I also have a while-loop that consumes the output of `command1` and produces its own:

```
$command1 | while read line;
    do 
        echo "   ${line/[1G/[4G}" 
    done
```

But I want to unify my script and put all the commands in the corresponding variables, so to be able to write something like this:

```
$command1 | $command2 | ...
```

Do I have any options in order to achieve that ?

Comment: Use functions instead of variables

Comment: @thatotherguy how ? I need them pipelined

Comment: Variables are for storing data, not executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, use functions:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

command1() {
  ls /home/yevhenii
}

command2() {
  while read line; do
    echo "   ${line/[1G/[4G}" 
  done
}

command1 | command2
```

That aside, you might want to drop `ls dir | while read line` in favor of `for line in dir/*`. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: thank you, worked out very well! 'ls' was just for example